# C++ Bit Operations - Hexadecimals

Tags: c++, hex

Could you please help me? As far as i know the decimal value of 0xA07F is: 16^3*10 + 0 + 16*7 +1*16= 41088. Then how do I shift this? The output is 2032.
Here is the code:

```
 unsigned short sh = 0xA07F; 
 sh = sh << 4; 
 cout << dec << sh << endl;
```

Comment: `0xF` is not 16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically have binary for `sh` as follows:

```
1010 0000 0111 1111
A      0    7    F
```

Then:

```
sh <<= 4

1010 0000 0111 1111 0000 //^^Note that you have three 0s before A if 32 bits
```

It becomes:

```
0xA07F0
```

However, since `sh` is `unsigned short`, it should be 2bytes, which is 16 bits. You should get:

```
0x07F0
```

the left most bytes are truncated, you should get `15 *16 + 7 * 256 = 2032` in decimal. You can see a live example here: http://ideone.com/Fy4PJr

Answer (score 5):

The reason the output is smaller than the value shifted is that you're overflowing the width of the type. Make `sh` an unsigned int and you will get the correct value.

```
 0xA07F == 1010_0000_0111_1111
```

If you right shift this by 4 you get

```
 1010_0000_0111_1111 << 4 == 1010_0000_0111_1111_0000
                             ^^^^
                             ^^^^
                             ^^^^
                             These bits overflow the width of the type
```

The short will be promoted to an unsigned integer, the shift will be done, but the result will be trucated back into a 16-bit short so you will only get the `0000_0111_1111_0000` portion of the `1010_0000_0111_1111_0000` result.

Answer (score 1):

Short only holds two bytes:
from(http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/)

> short int (short)     Short Integer.  2bytes  signed: -32768 to 32767
>   unsigned: 0 to 65535

As such, your code overflows, which is why the shift opearator decreases the value.

try:

```
 unsigned int sh = 0xA07F; 
 sh = sh << 4; 
 cout << dec << sh << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are starting with `0xA07F`, which is 16 bits long, then shifting left 4 bits, which would result in `0xA07F0`. you have declared `sh` as a short, therefore truncating the A and resulting in `0x07f0`.